# Can users change symbology of GP output operational layer with Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I built a very simple Python GP script tool in ***ArcMap 10.4.1*** that takes a user input file (e.g. csv) and returns a Point Feature Layer using XY coordinates from the input file.

After I published the results as GP service (no map service returned), I used *Web AppBuilder 2.3 (Dev Edition)* and set up my GP widget to return the output as an **operational layer**.

After I run the GP widget and get the result mapped, why am I not allowed/able to change the symbology of my operational layer?